# Integral over torus of given $2-$form.

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

Let $D$ denote the torus of revolution in $\Bbb{R}^3$ by revolving the circle

$$(y-2)^2+z^2=1,$$

along the $z-$axis.

If $\omega = z \, dx \wedge dy$, compute $\int_D \omega$.

**Attempt:**

So I am appealing to Stokes' theorem by computing

$$\int_M d \omega$$

where $M$ is the filled in torus (including the boundary) with one radius $2$ and one radius $1$. However, a quick computation shows

$$d \omega = dx \wedge dy \wedge dz.$$

Thus

$$\int_M d \omega$$

is just the volume of this torus which is

$$2\pi^2Rr^2$$

where $R=2$, $r=1$ so is the answer

$$4\pi^2??$$

Thanks in advance for any help!! so for Stokes' theorem, for any given exercise its always the case that one of the two sides of the equation will always be much more trivial to compute than the other side?

Comment: Looks correct but it is [not always](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4823770/949989) that simple.

Comment: I can't say that one side will always be easier to solve than the other.  But, it may be the case, and Stokes' theorem is a powerful tool.

Comment: @user317176 Please: The man's name was Stokes. So break bad habits and write either Stokes' Theorem or Stokes's Theorem.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for the correction.

Comment: @user317176 Thanks for correcting. Just keep this fact permanently in your mind! :)

Comment: But how do you know the formula for the volume of a torus? The usual way of deriving it would be by computing the integral.

Comment: To actually compute the integral (either over the surface or over the interior), I would write down the usual parametrisation of the torus in terms of "polar" coordinates and actually do the integral.

Comment: @AlexB. I looked it up tbh lol

Comment: Well, how look-upable something is is not a good measure for how easy it is, so your last sentence is not really connected to the rest of the post.